# Sorting by Time Units (e.g. ms, s, etc.) in Bash or Shell

Tags: bash, terminal, sorting

What would be the easiest way to sort a list of numbers appended with time units in bash or shell? In other words, I'm looking for something similar to "sort -h" but rather than sorting size units, I want to sort time units (ns, us, ms, s).

Here's an example list I wanted to sort:
1.234s
804.2754ms
603.223us
50.1234ms

Comment: good question.  to me this looks like 2 bugs in `sort -h`, or perhaps 1 bug and 1 un-fixable design limitation.  1) `us` or `µs` isn't properly handled (bug).  2) `s` isn't properly handled by itself (possible design limitation).  if you convert the `s` to another unit that works properly (`m`, `k`, `M`), `sort -h` gets it right.  (try it with `mg/kg/Mg` values!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to solve this problem:

1. Add a second column, with the times converted to the same unit
2. Sort the input on the second column
3. Drop the second column

You could do step 1 with an awk script, this script converts the time units to nanoseconds:

```
{
    time = $1;
    sub(/[a-z]+$/, "", time);
    unit = $1;
    sub(/^[^a-z]+/, "", unit);

    # convert to nanoseconds
    if (unit == "us") {
        time *= 1000;
    } else if (unit == "ms") {
        time *= 1000000;
    } else if (unit == "s") {
        time *= 1000000000;
    }
    print $1, time
}
```

If you save this in a file `convert.awk`, then you can perform steps 1-3 with this pipeline:

```
awk -f convert.awk input.txt | sort -g -k2 | cut -f1 -d' '
```

The `-g` instead of `-n` is necessary in case some numbers get displayed in exponential notation. (Credit to OP for pointing that out.)

Comment: Works pretty well. Minor thing: I noticed sometimes the output will be printed in exponential notation, so had to switch to using `sort -k2 -g`

Comment: @TLin nice, thanks for pointing that out, added to my answer

Comment: `-n` and `-g` options of `sort` incompatible, leave only `-g`